# How can I most efficiently get these group_by stats in MYSQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Suppose I have a MySQL table that was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `my_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `my_boolean_field` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table is very large. It has approximately 10 million rows in it. `my_boolean_field`'s only possible values are `1`, `0` and `null`.

Now separately, I have a list of 500 IDs. Let's call this `my_list`. They are in a text file separated by newlines. The name of that file is `myfile.txt`. The entries in this file are too long to include in a single `where` clause of an SQL statement.

I want to answer the following questions:

1. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is in `my_list` and my_boolean_field is null.
2. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==1.
3. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==0.
4. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is not in `my_list` and my_boolean_field is null.
5. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is not in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==1.
6. How many of the rows in `my_table` have and ID that is not in `my_list` and my_boolean_field==0.

What is the most performant way to get the above 6 counts??

Comment: why don't you load the text file into the database as a table? then the query would be a simple join.

Comment: Show me the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` and conditional aggregation to get the desired counts.

```
select 
 sum(l.id is not null and t.my_boolean_field is null)
,sum(l.id is not null and t.my_boolean_field =1)
,sum(l.id is not null and t.my_boolean_field =0)
,sum(l.id is null and t.my_boolean_field is null)
,sum(l.id is null and t.my_boolean_field =1)
,sum(l.id is null and t.my_boolean_field =0)
from my_table t
left join my_list l on l.id=t.my_id
```

The conditions in `sum` are treated as booleans and return 1 for true and 0 for false.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE list (
    `my_id` char(32) NOT NULL
);

LOAD DATA INFILE ... -- get the 500 rows into `list`.

SELECT 
    SUM(my_boolean_field IS NULL),
    SUM(my_boolean_field = 0),
    SUM(my_boolean_field = 1),
    SUM(my_boolean_field IS NOT NULL),
    SUM(my_boolean_field != 0),
    SUM(my_boolean_field != 1)
FROM tbl  AS t
JOIN list AS l ON t.my_id = l.my_id;
```

It will do the 500 lookups, tallying the 6 counters as it goes.